# A bot that calculates the time of members in our server logged in and send it

Tags: discord.js

I'm new to node js . I want to make a bot that calculates our study time and sends it in our channel
So ,when someone from our server message !login is should start the stopwatch and when he types !logout it should stop the stopwatch and the time to the previous and show the total time
Please help me , I want it done as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that would be to create a [`Collection`](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#collections) in the client, store the time when the user sends `!login` and then when the user sends `!logout`, fetch the started date from the client, calculate the time used, and then set the `Collection` to null. However one disadvantage of that is the fact that once the bot restarts, all the data is lost. But since I have no idea if you have any database already set up, we can use `Collections` for now. The completed code might look something like this:

```js
const { Collection } = require('discord.js')
// ...
client.userStudyTime = new Collection()
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content === '!login') { // Check if the message's content was !login
        const time = new Date() // Get the login time
        client.userStudyTime.set(message.author.id, time.getTime()) // Set the time
    }
    if (message.content === '!logout') { // Check if the message's content was !logout
        const userTime = client.userStudyTime.get(message.author.id) // Get the user's login time
        if (!userTime) return message.channel.send('You are not logged in!') // Check if the user had logged in
        const time = new Date().getTime() // Get the logout time
        const diff = time - userTime // Calculate the difference
        const hours = Math.round(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60) // Get the hours
        const minutes = Math.round(diff / 1000 / 60) // Get the minutes
        const seconds = Math.round(diff / 1000) // Get the seconds
        message.channel.send(`You studied for ${hours}hrs, ${minutes}min, ${Math.round(seconds)}sec`) // Reply back
        client.userStudyTime.set(message.author.id, null) // Set the collection to null
    }
});
// ...
```

Comment: i doubt he'll have a collection, if he's trying to save the amount of study time. this sounds like a project that uses a database of some sort. since collections are reset after   the bot is restarted.

Comment: Yeah, but since the OP did not mention anything else about databases or stuff, the next easiest thing is using collections. I also mentioned in the answer that restarting the bot would erase all data

Comment: Well , thanks it working but it's just resetting the times everytime so I need to find a answer for it , if you can please try to help me

Answer (score 0):

It would be unwise to have something like a stopwatch.
You want something that will store the user and the time they login, and then when the log out, calculate the time difference and send that.
That can be achieved with either a database, or a simple JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is save a timestamp when using `!login` with the `Date.now()` function, whether it be in a client collection or a database. And compare it to the timestamp when they use `!logout`, the difference between the two would be the amount of seconds they were logged in.

**Date.now() Function**

```js
Date.now(); // outputs a timestamp
```

*Output:*

```
1653579416
```

**Login Command**

> in the logout command, you're going to want to use the Date.now() function and set it in your database or your collection under the user that used the command.

**Logout Command**

> in the logout command you want to go back to the login timestamp, and subtract the current timestamp by the saved one, and the difference will be how many seconds they were logged in for.

**Example**

```js
var loggedInStamp // 1653579416 // you'll want to get this from wherever you saved it
var loggedOutStamp = Date.now() // 1653580205 // current timestamp

// subtract 1653580205 by 1653579416 which equals 789 //
// aka logged in for 789 seconds //
let amountTime = loggedOutStamp - loggedInStamp

return amountTime
/* this is what you want to add to the total time logged in */
```

This will make your database save the total time logged in seconds, there are plenty of modules or algorithms to convert seconds to minutes, hours, days...

**Here is a code example for converting seconds to hours and minutes:**

```js
function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}
```

This is a better way to get the amount of time logged in instead of using a stopwatch.